# Aptitude, Why does 400 years have 0 odd years?

Tags: math, calendar

```
Q The last day of a century cannot be  
    Monday               
    Friday  
    Wednesday          
    Tuesday
```

Answer: **Tuesday**

**Explanation:**

100 years contain 5 odd days. **==>** so Last day of 1st century is **Friday**.
200 years contain (5 x 2) 3 odd days. **==>** So Last day of 2nd century is **Wednesday**.
300 years contain (5 x 3) = 15 1 odd day. **==>** Last day of 3rd century is **Monday**.
400 years contain 0 odd day. **==>** Last day of 4th century is **Sunday**.

**This cycle is repeated.**
So Last day of a century cannot be Tuesday or Thursday or Saturday.

---

*Where I am stuck,*

200 years have 5x2 = 10 extra days, so `10%7 = 2` odd days.
300 years have 5x3 = 15 extra days, so `15%7 = 1` odd days.
400 years **should** have 5x4 = 20 extra days, so `20%7 =` **6 odd days**.

But it say 0 odd days **HOW and WHY??**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot that years numbered `k*400` are [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) while `k*400+100, k*400 +200, k*400+300` are not leap ones.

So 400 years give `20+1=21===0 mod 7` odd days

Answer (score 1):

MBos answer is correct.

If I'm not mistaken, year 2000 is past for quite some while now, every year divisible by 400 and 1000 without some rest counts as NOT a leap year, contrary to the 400 year rule MBo mentioned.

The problem is: a year is actually 365.2425 long. To keep all discrepancies as low as possible, these kind of goofy rules exist to minimize errors.